# In wordpress how to get post pecific image gallery for single post?

Tags: wordpress

I am new in wordpress and have very basic knowledge of php.
I have created post. And in the specific post I want to show gallery related to that product in one section and post's description in the other section.
I have couple of images in gallery for some spaecific posts wth featured image and description.
I have to show the specific post in a inner page with the specific gallery in one section and its description in another section with featured image.

Comment: You need to provide more information if anyone is going to be able to help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I guess that when you say gallery, you mean the featured image of the post.

So, to get that image, this could be a way

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ): ?>
<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
<div> <?php echo $image[0]; ?> </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can ge the image for the page

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>
echo $image[0];
```